# How to re-enable my touchpad on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, touchpad, xorg, xorg.conf

My touchpad is not working in my user on Ubuntu 10.10. However, when I logon as another user it works fine. I tried using `synclient` on my user and it says that `TouchpadOff=1`. I wonder what could be the problem, and how can I enable the touchpad on my user?

Answer (score 1):

Simple check is have you pressed the disable key combo

> fn + f1

form me it is fn + f1 to en able and disable the touch pad. Other computers have different key combos. It works with the hardware of the system I think so it might not be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't solve my problem. I don't think it's something related to hardware, since the touchpad works when I switch to another user (even without logout).

Comment: Thanks, in my computer (Acer Aspire One) it was Fn + F7.